# St 4700 shifter trim down question

Tags: shimano, derailleur-front

[image]I got a st 4700 tiagra shifter and fd r7000 front derailleur in double crankset. My problem is when i am in the big ring and try to trim down i pull the little lever on the shifter and hear a good click, feel the movememt in the cable but the front derailleur does not move? There is good amount of cable tension i checked. And also trim on the small ring works. Can this be a cable routing issue or is this normal?

UPDATE :I installed the tiagra fd-4700 derailleur and the trim works fine. Actually the 105 fd r7000 derailleur is not fully compatible with Tiagra shifters.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the shifters and FD are compatible?
4700 is 10 speed and r7000 is 11 speed

Comment: hi its the front derailleur not the rear derailluer, i think the front derailleurs are the same.

Comment: The Tiagra shifters are **not** officially compatible with 105 and higher front derailleurs. Shimano's compatibility is pretty conservative. I don't know if this setup could be made to work, however. https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-455

Comment: yes maybe, officially not compitable but a lot of thins works perfectly even shimano says its not compitable.

Comment: Is it worth checking if you've followed the FD installation procedure in the R7k FD manual? For that FD (and actually for the Tiagra FD as well), you need to shift to the top trim position to adjust cable tension. That is, you shift to the big ring, then trim the FD towards the little ring (but don't shift to the little ring). https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-RAFD001-05-ENG.pdf

Comment: yes i exactly did like that

Comment: Would you mind adding your own answer that states how you fixed the problem, then clicking the green tick/check to the left?  SE works better if there's an accepted answer, rather than editing the answer into your question.  Plus you get more reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update

I installed the tiagra fd-4700 derailleur and the trim works. Apparently the 105 fd-r7000 derailleur with Tiagra shifters are not fully compatible.

Comment: I pointed out the official compatibility issue in comments above. As you and I know, Shimano is conservative with their compatibility recommendations. I was struggling to explain why your derailleur wouldn't trim properly, especially since you said you feel the cable being released from the shifter when you hit trim. This does seem like it should work. Perhaps the 4700 shifter isn't releasing enough cable when trimmed for the 105 front derailleur to move? I'm not sure.

Comment: yes 4700 shifters and r7000 fd are not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is that the cable is not beign pulled through the hose. this can be caused by various things:

Get your chain on the bigger chainring and shift down, since the derailleur does not shift properly, try to move it by hand. if you feel just a little resistance you should check your routing and/or change hoses and cables. if the resistens is strong, do not apply to much force. In this case check if the limit adjuster screw is preventing the chain from moving onto the smaller chainring. you should find two screws on the derailleur which are responsible for setting the upper and lower bound, e.g. prevent your derailleur from moving the chain to far.

hope that helps!

PS.: make shure that the cable is routed the right way, it looks kind of wrong in the posted picture (near the point where the cable is clamped).

Comment: hi , thanks for the reply but the problem is with the trimming.i can shift to the smaller ring without problem( 2 clicks) .its the first click that does not move the derailleur( for using the bigger cogs on the back with big chainring on the front)

Comment: ah, alright. sry i did miss that. is the chain alreaty touching the front derailleur in this situation?

Comment: yes when i go big/big the chain starts to rub so i would like to trim down but the derailluer wouldnt move by the shifter click.

Comment: just an assumption but can it be possible that that the chain is already under so much sideways tension (in riders direction all the way left on the cassette and all the way right on the chainrings) that the front derailleur cant shift down? also on the picture the chain starts to bend to the left right after the chainring, maybe you have to shift to a lower gear (on the back, cassette) earlier in order to shift down on the smaller chainring.
anyway big/big is never a good option, it causes a lot of wear on chainrings and lengthens the chain

Comment: ok so you are saying that try to trim when around in the middle section of the back cassette, i will try it.